# show this equation has $m-1$ distinct real roots

Tags: trigonometry, roots

**interesting problem:**

> let postive integer $m$ such $b>1+\dfrac{1}{m}$ ,show that this equation
>   $$\sin{(m+1)x}+b\sin{(mx)}=0$$
>    has $m-1$ distinct real  roots on $(0,\pi)$

I have solve the simpler case $m=1,2$

**m=1**
$$\sin{(2x)}+b\sin{x}=0\Longrightarrow \sin{x}(2\cos{x}+b)=0$$
and $b>1+\dfrac{1}{m}=2$,if$x\in(0,\pi)$,then we have
$$\sin{x}(b+2\cos{x})>0$$
so for this case no solution

**m=2**

since
$$\sin{3x}+b\sin{2x}=3\sin{x}-4\sin^3{x}+2b\sin{x}\cos{x}=
\sin{x}(4\cos^2{x}+2b\cos{x}-1)$$
and by condition we have $b>\frac{3}{2}$,it Just to prove that
$$4\cos^2{x}+2b\cos{x}-1=0$$ has only one real solution $x\in(0,\pi)$ when $b>\dfrac{3}{2}$F or a quadratic equation is not hard to get

How to prove $m\ge 3$?

Comment: Have you tried strong induction?

Comment: I have try it,if $\sin{(m+1)x}+b\sin{(mx)}=0$ has $x_{1},x_{2},\cdots,x_{m-1}$ solution, then consider $f(x)=\sin{(m+2)x}+b'\sin{(m+1)x}$,it seem hard it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $f(x) = \sin((m+1)x)+b\sin(mx)$. Notice that if $x\in(0,\pi)$ satisfied $\cos(mx) = 0$ (i.e. $x = \left(i+\frac{1}{2}\right)\frac{\pi}{m}$ for some $0<i<m$), then $|\sin(mx)| = 1$, and hence
$$|f(x)| = |\sin((m+1)x)+b\sin(mx)|\ge |b||\sin(mx)| - |\sin((m+1)x)| >\left(1+\frac{1}{m}\right)(1) - 1 > 0. $$
Hence, if $x\in(0,\pi)$ is a root of $\cos(mx)$, then $x$ is not a root of $f$. So it suffices to find the roots of $g(x) = f(x)/\cos(mx)$ in $(0,\pi)\backslash\{\frac{\pi}{2m},\frac{3\pi}{2m},\dots,\frac{(2m-1)\pi}{2m}\}$. Notice that
\begin{align} g(x) &= \frac{\sin((m+1)x)+b\sin(mx)}{\cos(mx)} \\
&= \frac{\sin(mx)\cos(x) + \cos(mx)\sin(x) + b\sin(mx)}{\cos(mx)} \\
&= (b+\cos(x))\tan(mx) + \sin(x).
\end{align}
Since $b+\cos(x)>0$ for all $x$ (as $b>1$), it suffices to find the roots of $h(x) = g(x)/(b+\cos(x))$, i.e.
$$ h(x) = \tan(mx) + \frac{\sin(x)}{b+\cos(x)}. $$
Notice that
\begin{align} h'(x) &= m\sec^2(mx) + \frac{\cos(x)}{b+\cos(x)} + \frac{\sin^2(x)}{(b+\cos(x))^2} \\
&= m\sec^2(mx) + \frac{b\cos(x) + \cos^2(x)+\sin^2(x)}{(b+\cos(x))^2} \\
&= m\sec^2(mx) + \frac{b\cos(x)+1}{(b+\cos(x))^2}.
\end{align}
I now claim that $h'(x)>0$ for all $x\in(0,\pi)$ where $h$ is defined. Notice that this is clearly true when $b\cos(x)+1\ge 0$. For $x$ such that $b\cos(x)+1<0$, we see that $\frac{b\cos(x)+1}{(b+\cos(x))^2}$ is minimized (i.e. attains the greatest negative value) when $b\cos(x)+1$ is minimized and $(b+\cos(x))^2$ is minimized. Since $b>1$, both of these are minimized when $\cos(x) = -1$, i.e.
$$\frac{b\cos(x)+1}{(b+\cos(x))^2} \ge \frac{-b+1}{(b-1)^2} = \frac{1}{1-b} > \frac{1}{1-(1+1/m)} = -m.$$
for all $x\in(0,\pi)$. Hence
$$ h'(x) > m\sec^2(mx) - m = m\tan^2(mx)\ge 0 $$
for all $x\in(0,\pi)$. Now, for each interval of the form $\left(\left(i-\frac{1}{2}\right)\frac{\pi}{m},\left(i+\frac{1}{2}\right)\frac{\pi}{m}\right)$, with $1\le i\le m-1$, notice that $h$ is strictly increasing on this interval, while
\begin{align} \lim\limits_{x\rightarrow \left(\left(i-\frac{1}{2}\right)\frac{\pi}{m}\right)^{+}}{h(x)} &= -\infty \\
\lim\limits_{x\rightarrow \left(\left(i+\frac{1}{2}\right)\frac{\pi}{m}\right)^{-}}{h(x)} &= \infty.
\end{align}
Hence $h$ has precisely one root in $\left(\left(i-\frac{1}{2}\right)\frac{\pi}{m},\left(i+\frac{1}{2}\right)\frac{\pi}{m}\right)$ for each $1\le i\le m-1$. Now
\begin{align} \lim\limits_{x\rightarrow 0^{+}}{h(x)} &= 0\\
\lim\limits_{x\rightarrow\pi^{-}}{h(x)} &= 0
\end{align}
so $h$ does not have a root in $\left(0,\frac{\pi}{2m}\right)$ or $\left(\frac{(2m-1)\pi}{2m},\pi\right)$, as it is strictly increasing in these intervals as well. Thus, $h$ has one root in each interval $\left(\left(i-\frac{1}{2}\right)\frac{\pi}{m},\left(i+\frac{1}{2}\right)\frac{\pi}{m}\right)$ for $1\le i\le m-1$ and no roots elsewhere, so $h$ has $m-1$ roots. It follows that $g$, and hence $f$, has $m-1$ roots as well.

Answer (score 1):

Let $f(x)=\sin(mx+x)+b\sin(mx)$ for all $x\in [0,\pi]$, look at the points $x_k=\frac{k\pi}{m}$, where $k=0,\cdots,m$, then $f(x_k)=\sin(\frac{m+1}{m}\cdot k\pi)$. Since $k\pi<x_k<k\pi+\pi$, then $f(x_k)f(x_{k+1})<0$. So $f$ has at least $m-1$ different zeros in $(0,\pi)$.

On the other hand, since $f'(x)=(m+1)\cos(mx+x)+mb\cos(mx)=mb\left(\frac{m+1}{mb} \cos(mx+x)+\cos(mx) \right)$. Do some discussion of the sign $f'(x)$ when $x\in (x_k,x_{k+1})$. Use the condition $\frac{m+1}{mb}<1$.

I did not do the discussion, but I think it should work.

Comment: Thank,  but I think following How to prove  the key  $f'(x)$sign

Comment: Thanks to $b<1$, look at the sing of $f'(x_k)$. Notice that $f'(x_k)=mb(c\cos(mx_k+x_k)+(-1)^k)$ with $c=\frac{m+1}{mb}$, then $f'(x_k)<0$ if $k$ is odd; $f'(x_k)>0$ if $k$ is even, so $f'(x)$ has only ``one?'' root between $x_k$ and $x_{k+1}$